# Set the image of UIButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode8, swift3

I want to set the image of a UIButton on a particular event. This is what I did:

```
btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "star"))
```

Comment: What is the issue with this?

Comment: Not enough context to answer.

Answer (score 15):

**Objective-C**

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];                
[btn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Swift 3**

```
let img = UIImage(named: "star")
btn.setImage(img , forState: .normal)
```

Comment: In Swift3 should use lowercase forState like .normal